# Apache wont start on MacOS Monterey

Tags: macos, apache

$ /usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
dyld[27461]: Symbol not found: _apr_bucket_alloc_aligned_floor
Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/httpd/2.4.51/bin/httpd
Expected in: /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib
Abort trap: 6

edit:

`brew reinstall apr-util` has resolved this

Comment: `brew reinstall apr-util` worked for me, too!

Comment: That brew command helped. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Thanks - this fix worked for me too.  This appears to be an essential step.  After upgrading to Monterey I followed the steps at
https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-monterey-apache-multiple-php-versions
but could not get apache to work.  When I ran `ps -aef | grep httpd` it showed that the server was not running, even though the brew services command claimed it was.  After running the reinstall command set out above, everything worked as before the upgrade.  For background, I am running Mac OS Monterey on a Mac mini with Apple M1 chip 16GB RAM.   My httpd.conf settings are the same as when I was on Big Sur.  I can't imagine how you worked this out, but thanks again.

OK - apparently my response above was not sufficiently clear:
Thomas posted the error message he got when he found that the Apache server would not start when being set up on Mac OS Monterey. The question he implicitly asked (and answered himself) is in the title of the post - ie., why won't the server start?  The error message he got gives us a clue - the process is looking for a component (`apr-util`) which it can't find in the place it expects to find it. He found that by re-installing `apr-util` he could get the Apache server to start as normally expected. I had the same problem (Apache apparently correctly installed on Monterey but not starting) and I found that by re-installing `apr-util` as he had that the problem was solved - ie., my Apache server now starts as expected on Mac OS Monterey. As I had wasted about a week futilely trying to solve this problem I am very grateful for Thomas' contribution.  I hope this is now clear.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Unfortunately, When I try that I get Error: /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.1.0 is not a directory

Comment: After following (again) the instructions  at https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-monterey-apache-multiple-php-versions, and reinstall apr-util I get: Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/woo/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist` exited with 5.

Comment: ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist contains
 <array>
  <string>/usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd</string>
  <string>-D</string>
  <string>FOREGROUND</string>
 </array>
and that is NOT where home-brew puts https, instead it's at /usr/loca/bin/httpd.  Even if I edit that plist to point to /usr/local/bin/httpd, it changes it back! and fails.

Comment: I'm still having this issue on a 2015 intel MBP

Comment: I think you have to be in the php8.1.0 directory when you run the `brew reinstall apr util` command otherwise you get told it is not a directory.  Also, I think that some of the other errors that John has reported may be caused by there being more than one installation of Apache on the machine - ie., you think you are issuing a command to one of them, but it is going to the other. You can find out which apache is responding by the command `which apachectl ` which will return the path to the active apache.  Maybe using brew to un-install apache and then re-installing from the start will work?